# MS Access Form Textbox not Editable

Tags: ms-access

I have setup a textbox in a form in Access.  The form is linked to a table.  But the textbox it self is unbound, it is used to simply gather user input.  However, I can't edit the value went it's viewed.

The textbox is not locked.  The textbox can be set value in VBA.  Textbox have no ControlSource.  I can edit it in DesignView.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, you are aboslutely right, that fixed it.

Comment: @JeffO Yea, if you submit it as the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Just ran into the same thing - I had set the form to not be editable.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, make sure the Form Property "Allow Edits" is set to "Yes"

Comment: Thanks bud for helping me out on this decade old question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think vba controls have two properties which can cause this.  Locked and Enabled.  Is the textbox enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause of this issue (to help others in my situation):  If you are opening your form using VBA and the DoCmd.OpenForm method, make sure your 5th parameter is not "acFormReadOnly"!

Not editable text boxes:

> DoCmd.OpenForm stFormName, , , , acFormReadOnly, acWindowNormal, stLinkCriteria

Editable text boxes:

> DoCmd.OpenForm stFormName, , , , acFormPropertySettings, acWindowNormal, stLinkCriteria

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when looking at the Form in 'Layout view'. When in 'Form View' of 'Datasheet View' the text box can be edited